# JavaScript: How do I split a string with multiple separators and exclude the separators?

Tags: javascript, regex

[According to this,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#splitting_with_a_regexp_to_include_parts_of_the_separator_in_the_result) "If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses (), matched results are included in the array." To me, that's an unwanted side effect. I would like to split on a `\n` or a `<br>` string, and I don't know how to do this without using parentheses around it:

```
string.split(/(\n|\<br\>)/)
```

is there a way of writing this regex without parentheses? I don't want to include the separators in the result. Here's an example of it working incorrectly:

```js
console.log("hi\nbye<br>foo".split(/(\n|\<br\>)/))
```

Comment: See [What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Just remove the parentheses ??

Comment: Dupe of [javascript regex split produces too many items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516040/javascript-regex-split-produces-too-many-items)

Comment: @CertainPerformance yep. I feel like an idiot. Aren't there certain situations where you have to wrap parens around an "or"? Did I just imagine that?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree.

Comment: Sure, eg: `a(b|c)` matches `ab` or `ac`. If in a situation like that and the capturing is a problem, use a non-capturing group instead. Generally, only use a capturing group when you *need* the capturing; use non-capturing by default when you just want logical grouping.

Comment: All right, should i just delete this, or leave it around to help people find the answer when they Google?

Comment: You need paranthesis around alternation (`|`) if you have something like `a(b|c)d` where you want to match either `abd` or `acd`, whereas `ab|cd` matches either `ab` or `cd`. However, in this case it's not really needed as you still have `<pattern1> or <pattern2>` expression.